# ejb jta nullpointer exception not rolling back

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have an EJB Stateless Session Bean, like this:

```
public void persist(Customer customer,Child child){  
try{  
   em.persist(customer); 
   Father father = new Father();
   father.setChild(child); here child is null 
   em.persist(father);
   }catch(Exception e){  

   }    
}
```

When the exception (NullPointerException) occurs the transaction is not rolling back and Customer entity is persisted, but when i catch the exception with

```
   public void persist(Customer customer,Child child){  
   try{  
    em.persist(customer); 
    Father father = new Father();
    father.setChild(child); here child is null 
    em.persist(father);
   }catch(EJBException e){  

   }    
}
```

the transaction is rolling back, but i don´t understand why, NullPointerException extends RuntimeException.The docs say a RuntimeException cause a rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example the `NullPointerException` is not caught, instead, you are catching an `EJBException` which is other runtime exception class.

As you say, when the Container intercepts the `NullPointerException`, the transaction is marked for rollback.

The first example catches `Exception`, wich is a base class (the Java exceptions are hierarchical ), 
therefore, any subclass of `Exception` such as `NullPointer` or `EJBException` 
is caught. In this case the Container doesn't mark the transaction for rollback.